# Tkinter Scrollbar Grayed Out

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, scrollbar

I have a GUI with a message box at the bottom (a frame containing a canvas, another frame inside that canvas, and a scrollbar). Everything appears in the window properly, but the scroll bar is always grayed out and there is no way to scroll. Anyone know how to fix it? (I know some people have asked a similar question, but I haven't been able to fix my code with any of the answers I've read.)

```
    frmMess = Frame(self.window)
    frmMess.pack(side = BOTTOM)
    frmMess.pack(expand = True, fill = X)
    frmMess.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: msgPark.configure(width=e.width-10))         

    self.canvas_main = Canvas(frmMess)
    self.canvas_main.pack(side = LEFT)
    self.canvas_main.pack(expand = True, fill = X)
    self.canvas_main.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: msgPark.configure(width=e.width-10)) 
    self.canvas_main.configure(scrollregion = self.canvas_main.bbox('all'))


    self.frmMessageBox = Frame(self.canvas_main, bg = self.bgcolor_m)
    self.frmMessageBox.pack(side = BOTTOM)
    self.frmMessageBox.pack(expand = True, fill = X)
    self.frmMessageBox.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: msgPark.configure(width=e.width-10)) 

    messageScroll = Scrollbar(frmMess, orient = "vertical")
    self.canvas_main.configure(yscrollcommand = messageScroll.set)
    messageScroll.pack(side = LEFT, fill = Y)
    messageScroll.configure(command = self.canvas_main.yview)
```

I call a function later that puts messages inside the embed frame (which is originally empty). I don't know if the problem is coming from the fuction I call later on, or the original set up

```
addMessage():
    event = myString
    msgPark = Message(self.frmMessageBox, text = event, bg = self.bgcolor_m,
                      pady = 5, padx = 10)
    msgPark.pack(expand = True, fill = X)
    msgPark.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: msgPark.configure(width=e.width-10))
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You're setting the bbox before you put anything on the canvas. Your first step should be to check what you're actually setting the bbox to in order to validate your assumption about what it's being set to.